# 3D transforms take up space even if taken out of flow?

Tags: css, css-transforms

I'm rotating a div in 3D space. It's pretty simple:

```
<div class="holder">
  <div class="box">
    <p>This is some text.</p>
 </div>
</div>

.box {
    background: orange;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 6em;
    transform: rotateY(60deg);
    padding: 20px;
    position: absolute;
}
.holder {
    perspective: 300px;
    max-width: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

I notice that in IE11 and Firefox, if the transform makes the shape run out of the viewport, it will display scrollbars. This happens even if the item is out of the flow, by setting position: absolute. In Chrome, no scrollbars are displayed.

My understanding was that 3D transforms don't take up any additional space than the non-3D version of the item, so I'm not sure whey scrollbars are appearing in some browsers. Is this the correct behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is correct behavior as per spec: http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-transforms-1/#transform-rendering

> For elements whose layout is governed by the CSS box model, the transform property does not affect the flow of the content surrounding the transformed element. However, the extent of the overflow area takes into account transformed elements. This behavior is similar to what happens when elements are offset via relative positioning. Therefore, if the value of the overflow property is scroll or auto, scrollbars will appear as needed to see content that is transformed outside the visible area.

Common workaround for this kind of behavior would be setting `overflow: hidden` on `html` element and then reseting it to `auto` or `scroll` lower in the DOM, based on your needs.